# Xcode how to add IBAction for opening an image?

Tags: xcode, ios, ibaction

HI,
I am trying to open an image by clicking a button,
in my `.h` i have

```
@interface FirstDetailViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *premi;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *figura;

    UIButton *apri;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *apri;

@end
```

in my `.m` file

```
@implementation FirstDetailViewController


- (IBAction)apri:(id)sender {


}
```

which code I have to use ?
thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You would also need to include `- (IBAction)apri:(id)sender;` in your **.h**.

Your logic is right as far as the button usage, you would connect `premi` to `apri:` in Interface Builder.

AS far as "opening" an image, there are many ways to handle an image. You can load a UIImageView with a specified image, or use a UIWebView, or many other ways.

Comment: wow that was quickly, thanks. I connected premi to apri. How can I load the UIImageView then?